IndexError in `sentence_vae_opt_inference.py`: position_ids out of range for embed_positions layer in SentenceVAE
I'm working on a project with a sentence_vae_opt_inference.py file, where I'm facing an IndexError: index out of range in self when passing position_ids to the embed_positions layer of my model. I’ve attempted various debugging and adjustments to resolve this, but the error persists.
Project Files

Primary Python File: sentence_vae_opt_inference.py
Supporting Notes File: README.md
Link to code

Error Overview
The error occurs specifically when position_ids are passed to embed_positions. It seems that position_ids exceeds the allowed index range for embed_positions, even though the values appear to be within limits based on my print-debugging.
Steps I’ve Taken

Checked Embedding Configuration

max_position_embeddings is set to 2048.
embed_positions.weight.shape[0] (positional embedding matrix size) is 2050.


Debugging Output

Position IDs max: 36
Position IDs shape: torch.Size([1, 37])
Embedding layer max index: 2049
Positional Embedding Matrix shape: torch.Size([2050, 2048])


Offset Adjustment

Tried setting the offset for position_ids to zero, but this didn’t resolve the issue:

if hasattr(self.model.decoder.embed_positions, 'offset'):
    self.model.decoder.embed_positions.offset = 0



Clamped position_ids

Used clamping to prevent position_ids from exceeding the embedding matrix’s range:

max_pos_emb = min(self.model.config.max_position_embeddings, self.model.decoder.embed_positions.weight.shape[0]) - 1
position_ids = torch.arange(0, inputs["input_ids"].shape[1]).clamp(max=max_pos_emb).unsqueeze(0).to(inputs["input_ids"].device)


However, the IndexError still persists.



Observed Behavior
Despite clamping position_ids, I’m still seeing an out-of-bounds error when passing them to embed_positions.
Remaining Challenges
The main challenge is aligning position_ids with the embed_positions range, as none of the above methods resolved the error. As potential next steps, I'm considering:

Further analysis of embed_positions behavior.
Trying alternative embedding strategies, such as fixed-length position encoding or bypassing embed_positions.

Question:
What could be causing this persistent out-of-bounds issue, even when position_ids values seem within limits? Are there any insights into handling position_ids alignment with embed_positions, or might there be an alternative approach to address this error?

Welcome to SO! Since this is a debugging question, please provide a [mre] and code-formatted text. A GitHub link isn't quite enough.
